Unable to create AWS cluster service due to `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication`
I am working on a springboot app,
containerize it using docker and pushed it to AWS ECR.
The issue is when I tried to deploy and run a task using the image,
I need to create a service, and I got an error.
Checked the logs it showed:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
at com.portfolio.quizapp.QuizappApplication.main(QuizappApplication.java:10)

I tried changing the dependencies, check the versions, include some other dependencies, but no avail. Here's a snapshot of my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.portfolio</groupId>
    <artifactId>quizapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>quizapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        
    <start-class>com.portfolio.quizapp.QuizappApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
            <!-- <mainClass>com.portfolio.quizapp.QuizappApplication</mainClass>
            <layout>JAR</layout> -->
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



This seems like a problem with the way you are creating your docker image. This is probably completely unrelated to AWS. You need to build your docker image and get it running locally first, to verify your build process, before even attempting to deploy to AWS.

Yes you're right! Now it works.
